# Open Windows Explorer in specific folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'd like Windows Explorer to open my Dropbox folder whenever I open Windows Explorer, instead of the My Documents folder.

To achieve this, I right-clicked on the Explorer icon in the task bar, then again right-clicked on the `Windows Explorer` entry, then `Properties`. There I changed Target to:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe c:\Users\myUsername\Dropbox
```

This works, but Windows Explorer opens the Dropbox folder in the hierarchy

```
Desktop\My Computer\C:\Users\myUsername\Dropbox
```

But I want it to open the hierarchy

```
Desktop\myUsername\Dropbox
```

If it opens `My Documents` (the default), it's that hierarchy too.

**Any idea how to achieve this?**

**EDIT:** To clarify, two screenshots. To the left is what I want. To the right is the hierarchy I get.

[image] [image]

Comment: what do you mean with hierarchy? Please post a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Set target to `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:usersfilesfolder\dropbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line instead: `%UserProfile%\Dropbox`

This should work. I don't know of a way to get the same result while still retaining the `%windir%\explorer.exe` part.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make any difference. Do you know of a way to do this without retaining the `%windir%\explorer.exe` part?

Comment: If I use `%UserProfile%\Dropbox` as the full target, it works exactly like you want on my Windows 7 machine. If I prepend the path to `explorer.exe` in the beginning it doesn't. This shouldn't be a problem since a new explorer window is opened implicitly, though.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work the way I want. It still opens the full hierarchy (the one on the left).

Comment: Just tested this in a fresh VM install, works exactly as you want.

Comment: Tested on two machines, it opens the hierarchy shown on the right side of my screenshot, not the one on the left.